# Procedural macro to auto-generate match

Tags: rust, metaprogramming

I am writing a toy virtual machine, where I need to decode instructions. I have an `Instruction` trait with some methods and concrete instructions implement this trait. Also, I have a decode function which just takes a byte and matches it to return a specific instruction corresponding to the byte given.

```rust
pub struct FirstInstruction { ... }

pub struct SecondInstruction { ... }

pub struct ThirdInstruction { ... }

pub fn decode(byte: u8) -> Box<dyn Instruction> {
  match byte {
    0x1 => Box::new(FirstInstruction::new()),
    0x2 => Box::new(SecondInstruction::new()),
    0x3 => Box::new(ThirdInstruction::new()),
  }
}
```

I was wondering how to write a procedural macro that would allow me to auto-generate the decode function. At the same time, it will get the byte to match in its arguments like this:

```rust
#[instruction(0x1)]
pub struct FirstInstruction { ... }

#[instruction(0x2)]
pub struct SecondInstruction { ... }

#[instruction(0x3)]
pub struct ThirdInstruction { ... }
  
pub fn decode(byte: u8) -> Box<dyn Instruction> {
  // Autogenerated
}
```

I understand that from the practical standpoint this whole thing can be useless. I am just curious about how it can be implemented using macros, if it is even possible.

I tried to read about how to write procedural macros, but I don't understand how one can accumulate information about all structs with the specific attribute and then generate a whole new function.

Comment: In general this is impossible, however there are tricks that may make this possible.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day I found out that this is pretty hard to implement.
I decided to stick to a simple macro that would generate the `decode` function:

```
macro_rules! register_instructions {
    {
        $(
            $code_value:expr => $struct_name:ty
        ),*
    } => {
        pub fn decode(code: &[u8]) -> Box<dyn Instruction> {
            let instruction_code = code[0];
            match instruction_code {
                $($code_value => Box::new(<$struct_name>::new(code))),*,
                _ => panic!("Invalid instruction"),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it looks like this:

```
register_instructions! {
    0x01 => AddInstruction,
    0x02 => SubInstruction,
    0x03 => MulInstruction,
    0x04 => DivInstruction,
    0x05 => JumpInstruction,
    0x06 => LoadInstruction,
    0x07 => FinishInstruction,
    0x08 => OutInstruction,
    0x09 => EqualInstruction,
    0x0A => LessInstruction,
    0x0B => LessEqualInstruction,
    0x0C => LoadAbsoluteInstruction
}
```